# Firebase cloud functions multiple transactions in one function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a cloud function that executes two transactions at once.

I have tried to do the following, only the first transaction executes... When I add the second it doesn't work and I get no errors.

Function:

```
exports.followIncrement = functions.database
.ref("/followers/{userId}").onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  const userId = context.params.userId;
  const currentUserUid = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0];

  console.log(currentUserUid);
  console.log(userId);

  var followerCount = 
admin.database().ref('users').child(userId).child('followerCount')
  var followingCount = 
admin.database().ref('users').child(currentUserUid).child('followingCount')

return followerCount.transaction((currentCount) => {
  return currentCount || 0 + 1;
})
.then(() => {
  return followingCount.transaction((currentCount) => {
      return currentCount || 0 + 1;
    })
  })
})
```

I appreciate all the feedback! 
Cheers.

Comment: What is `currentUserUid` if you log it?  Is everything in your function exactly the way you expect?

Comment: @DougStevenson Hi Doug. Yes, everything is what I expect. The `currentUserUid` is the uid of the authenticated user. When you follow another user, your uid gets placed under their uid node as a boolean. my uid (user who follows someone) is equal to the key which is where `Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0]` returns what I need to store the count under the correct node.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do something like:

```
return followerCount.transaction((currentCount) => {
  return currentCount || 0 + 1;
})
.then((count) => {
  if (count.committed) {
    return followingCount.transaction((currentCount) => {
      return currentCount || 0 + 1;
    })
  }
})
```